# Update wordpress custom field date format

Tags: mysql, wordpress, date, format

In a serious oversight on my part, I have sorted all date formats as `%M %d %Y (July 3 2012)` rather than `%Y %m %d (2012 07 03)`.

I want to convert all of the dates of a custom field (called 'game_release_date') to the new format.

The code I've got so far (but doesn't work) is:

```sql
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` 
SET meta_key = DATE(STR_TO_DATE(game_release_date, '%m %d %Y'))
WHERE DATE(STR_TO_DATE(game_release_date, '%M %d %Y'));
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  Your date format `%B/%e/%Y` does not make sense (`%B` is not a valid [format specifier](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)).  Furthermore you say you want `%Y%m%d` but then have `%m/%d/%Y` in your SQL and none of your formats reconcile with the example date strings you give.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where those '/' came from. I took the format names from here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_(Unix)) as I didn't know what they are.

Basically I want to convert all of the dates within the custom field 'release_date' from the format of July 3 2012 to 2012 07 03.

Comment: So looking at the link you sent me (i.e. the right one).

I want to turn %M %d %Y into &Y %m %d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the string containing `July 03 2012` into a MySQL date, use MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
STR_TO_DATE(game_release_date, '%M %d %Y')
```

I'd recommend storing the result of this function in a column of the [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) datatype.

To convert a MySQL date (whether the result of the above function, or a `DATE` column) into `2012 07 03`, use MySQL's [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function:

```
DATE_FORMAT(date_value, '%Y %m %d')
```

Therefore, if you want to keep your dates in a string (generally a bad idea) but in the new format:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET    game_release_date = DATE_FORMAT(
         STR_TO_DATE(game_release_date, '%M %d %Y'),
         '%Y %m %d'
       )
WHERE  meta_key = ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can store it as a date as it's a custom field in WordPress thus stored under the "meta_value" column with a corresponding "meta_key".

I assume that I'd use "WHERE meta_key = game_release_date" to make sure I only affect those.

Using the suggested code (along with meta_key = game_release_date) I get the following error: "#1054 - Unknown column 'game_release_date' in 'field list'"

Comment: @DavidHoward: Oh! `game_release_date` is your `meta_key`, not a custom field (as suggested in your question)?  In that case, you will need to replace all references to `game_release_date` above with `meta_value` and then have `WHERE meta_key = 'game_release_date'`.

Comment: A custom field called "game_release_date" would become a meta_key wouldn't it? I thought it always did. Then the info within the custom field would become a meta_value.

Comment: @DavidHoward: Talking cross-purposes.  A *field* in MySQL is another term for a column within the table.  I now understand that you meant a field in *Wordpress*.  See my previous comment.

Comment: Ah. Doing so set all the meta_values to NULL.

This was the query I used: 

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(meta_value, '%M %d %Y'),'%Y %m %d') WHERE meta_key = 'game_release_date'

Comment: @DavidHoward: The query looks right; are you sure that the original dates were in `%M %d %Y` format?

Comment: Yeah, they're stored as "longtext" and look like this "December 3, 2010".

Comment: @DavidHoward: There is a comma in there?  And the days of the month are only single-digits?  Then the format string should be `%M %e, %Y`.